# Undefined const while reading API request

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react-native and trying to get information from a request on an API. My problem is that the API is not very consistent... I get the properties of beers by entering a request on my app then I would like to get the image url of my beer. It's supposed to be under the property labels.icon but sometimes there is not such properties.

So when I'm trying to render the image I get an error.

Components/Search.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Button, FlatList, Text } from 'react-native';
import AleItem from './AleItem';
import {getAleFromApiWIthSearchText} from '../API/BreweryDB' 


class Search extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.searchedText= ""
    this.state = {
      ales: []
    }
  }

  _searchTextInputChanged(text) {
    this.searchedText = text
  }

  _loadAle() {
    if (this.searchedText.length > 0) { // Seulement si le texte recherché n'est pas vide
      getAleFromApiWIthSearchText(this.searchedText).then(data => {
          this.setState({ ales: data.data })
      })
    }
}

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main_container}>
        <TextInput 
          style={styles.textinput}
          placeholder='Titre du film'
          onChangeText={(text) => this._searchTextInputChanged(text)}
        />
        <Button title='Rechercher' onPress={() => this._loadAle()}/>
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.ales}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
            renderItem={({item}) => <AleItem ale={item}/>}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main_container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 30
  },
  textinput: {
    marginBottom: 5,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    height: 50,
    borderColor: '#000000',
    borderWidth: 1,
    paddingLeft: 5
  }
})

export default Search
```

API/breweryDB.js

```
const API_TOKEN = "MY API TOKEN"

export function getAleFromApiWIthSearchText(text) {
    const url = 'https://sandbox-api.brewerydb.com/v2/search?q='+text+'&type=beer&key='+API_TOKEN+'&format=json'
    return fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .catch((erro) => console.log(error))
}
```

Components/AleItem.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image } from 'react-native'

class AleItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const ale = this.props.ale
    const aleImage = ""

    try {
      this.props.ale.labels.icon;
      aleImage = this.props.ale.labels.icon;
    } catch(e) {
      aleImage = "";
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.main_container}>
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={{uri: aleImage}}
        />
        <View style={styles.content_container}>
          <View style={styles.header_container}>
            <Text style={styles.title_text}>{ale.name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.vote_text}>{ale.ibu}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.description_container}>
            <Text style={styles.description_text} numberOfLines={6}>{ale.description}</Text>
            {/* La propriété numberOfLines permet de couper un texte si celui-ci est trop long, il suffit de définir un nombre maximum de ligne */}
          </View>
          <View style={styles.date_container}>
            <Text style={styles.date_text}>{ale.type}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main_container: {
    height: 190,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  image: {
    width: 120,
    height: 180,
    margin: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'gray'
  },
  content_container: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 5
  },
  header_container: {
    flex: 3,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  title_text: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 20,
    flex: 1,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    paddingRight: 5
  },
  vote_text: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 26,
    color: '#666666'
  },
  description_container: {
    flex: 7
  },
  description_text: {
    fontStyle: 'italic',
    color: '#666666'
  },
  date_container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  date_text: {
    textAlign: 'right',
    fontSize: 14
  }
})

export default AleItem;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Search from './Components/Search';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Search/>
    );
  }; 
};
```

I tried to add a if condition under my image in order to use the aleImage only if the variable is defined but it seems the React native image object cannot be used with if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<Image source={(aleimg=== "") ? defaultImage : { uri: aleimg}} />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have two questions for you then :
1) I would like to understando your code : if aleimg === "" then the default url is going to be aleimg but what is happenning if aleimg !== "" ?
2) I get an error "can't find variable : aleImage". I don't get it because I have declared my const above using 

`
render() {
    const ale = this.props.ale
    
    if (this.props.ale.labels.icon) {
      const aleImage = this.props.ale.labels.icon;
    } else {
      const aleImage = ""; 
    }
`

Comment: if aleimg === "" then you need to specify a default image url, if aleimg!="" then it will show your image which you are getting from API.